# How to import an existing directory to an orphan branch

Tags: git, version-control

### tl;dr

What I want is a tidy way to push code from my web servers to orphan branches in a remote repository without leaving any Git repo's on the web server afterwards and without having to clone the entire remote repository onto the Web server first. I also need to leave the current, unversioned, files untouched on the web server.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I am not asking for a way to setup deployment or anything of the sort, I already have that working. I simply need a way to push the existing code from a non-versioned directory to a new orphan branch in a remote repository tidily without messing up and files on the webserver and without leaving any `.git` files behind.

### Background Information

I've recently gotten into the trend of using Git for versioning all my websites. It seems so much easier than FTPing things, and allows working in teams all with full history and revisions. I am going through the process of importing everything into Git repos, but I've hit a bit of an issue.

I have a project that will have multiple (orphan) branches that represent different deployment targets for code. For the purpose of this question this is what my setup looks like:

I have 3 servers. Two are Web Servers and 1 is a hybrid Web-Git Server.

One of the Web Servers is a small VM that operates as a CDN backend for Cloudflare. It runs an nginx server and simply serves and changed or new files once or twice to Cloudflare for caching (its small because Cloudflare only requests the file once, meaning it doesn't handle large amounts of requests).

My second Web Server hosts the actual Website and contains the entire server backend for the app.

Both of the Web Servers are, for illustrational purposes, separate machines. The third machine is simply the Git server and hosts a bunch of Atlassian apps.

I also had a previous SVN repository that contained C# Source code for a server related to the project.

### The Problem

I have imported the existing SVN repository into the "master" of the Git repository. I now want to create 2 orphan branches, one for the CDN files and one for the website files.

After some research I have come across something like this: `git checkout --orphan <branchname>`. This is where my problem lies. I would like to create a branch to push CDN etc. code to and then push the code from the current web servers without having to clone the entire repository. Because `git checkout` requires an existing git repo to be in the working directory, I didn't know how to do this. I tried `git init`-ing the directory where my files are, creating a new branch locally, comitting them and then pushing them to a remote branch with `git push git@mydomain.com:me/the_repo +local_branch:cdn_branch` but this didn't work and left a Git repository in my web servers WWW folder.

Comment: What I'm confused with is why the choice to go with orphan branches.  From what I've seen with Git release cycle flows, one tags a branch, and releases the tag instead.  If you have multiple directories that require special handling, then you would have multiple Git repositories.  Also, there's no harm in having the source code in source control, since you can always go back to an older version.  Are tags not a viable option for you?

Comment: @Makoto If you are referring to me asking for no Git repo to be left behind after when you say: "there is no harm in having the source code in source control", What I meant was that I have a separate way of VHosting my repos so that the repo isn't actually in my /var/www folder. All my code is currently there so I need a way to do a "drive-by" push without leaving behind a Repo afterwards.

Comment: @Makoto The reason we go for Orphan branches is it allows us to keep track of projects easier. We will probably go the way of separate repo's for each part in the future, but for now it keeps our Git host tidier to use branches. Also, my current deployment script works based on branches so it's easier to use orphans than rewrite my script.

Comment: I dunno...this sounds pretty unconventional.  Normally the code would be stored in a place that's independent of where it needs to be deployed, and you'd have a deploy script to put it in /var/www.  I'm definitely more of a conventional user of Git, so I wouldn't be able to help you out much in this case.

Comment: @Makoto That is exactly what I have. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I have a script running on my Web server that is called via a post-commit hook on the git server via a POST request. This script then executes a Bash script which works out what it needs to do, and then runs a `git fetch` from wherever. I simply need a way to tidily get the source code versioned in the first place. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip a lot of that:

```
cd /var/www
git init
git add .
git commit -m"Importing existing code to branch blah"
git push u://r/l master:blah
rm -rf .git
```

Comment: This works just the same, so I'll make this one as correct :)

Comment: Heh.  Naah, you had it already, clean yours up & put it back :-)

Comment: Done! (Sadly I have to wait 18 hours to mark mine as the answer)

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I came to the following solution:

1. First goto the directory you wish to push to the orphan branch

   EG: `cd /var/www`
2. Initialize an empty Git Repository

   EG: `git init .`
3. Add all the files from the current directory

   EG: `git add .`
4. Commit them

   EG: `git commit -m "Importing existing code to branch blah"`
5. Push the branch to the remote repo

   EG: `git push <URL> master:<BRANCH NAME>`
6. Clean up time

   EG: `rm -fr .git`

That did it for me without having to clone the entire Git Repository down onto my webserver! What got me for some time was the fact that the orphaned branch will only be created once you commit files to it. Multiple times I tried `git checkout --orphan BRANCH` and confused me because the branch didn't show when I typed in `git branch`.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't even need `--orphan` on step 4, plain `git checkout -b` would work too.  There's nothing in the repo so there is no previous commit for the new branch-head to point-to, which is why `git branch` can't show it until you commit (it won't show the [lack of] `master` either).  Also, if you intend to bring the code *back* from the remote you added, use `git push -u` in step 7 to mark the remote as the "upstream" for the new branch.

Comment: Oh, comment on prev comment, I somehow completely missed step 8.  Simplify with [jthill's version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19336434/1256452).

Answer (score 0):

A way to merge two repositories is to simply copy the objects from one `.git/objects` directory to the other.

After copying `repoA/.git/objects/*` to `repoB/.git/objects/`, objects (commits and revisions of files, not branches and simple tags) of repoA should appear in repoB as-is.

Commits imported from repoA are not pointed by any branch of repoB, so they will be dangling commits for a moment. You can create a branch pointing at those imported commits in repoB afterwards.

A possible risk is that conflicting SHA1 hash may exist (just mentioning the possibility, this shouldn't occur often).

======

Not pretty sure if I understood what you want to do. Maybe you want to manage portion of contents with git submodule?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would like to commit to one server and release to another two without having all the files, history, etc., on the release server(s) - I would suggest setting up post commit filters for tags that copy the release files to those other two servers.